# Deleting certain files using python

Tags: python

I have a py script that processes files with extension '.hgx'.Example : test.hgx
( there are many such files with extension hgx)

The script processes the test.hgx and creates a new test_bac.hgx and on re-run it creates test_bac_bac.hgx. So everytime running the script creates a file with **'_bac'.**

Is there some solution that I can use in my script that can delete all the existing **'_bac' and '_bac_bac...'** files before start of the actual code.

I am already using glob.glob function

```
for hgx in glob.glob("*.hgx"):
```

Can I use this function to delete these files 'X_bac.hgx' and other _bac_bac..hgx files?

Any help/idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
import os
import glob
for hgx in glob.glob("*_bac.hgx"):
  os.remove(hgx)
```

Answer (score 8):

A very similar solution would be

```
import os
import glob
map(os.remove, glob.glob("*_back.hgx"))
```

But besides having a slightly more compact expression, you save one variable name in the current namespace.

Comment: In Python 3, you need to then _invoke_ the generator returned by `map`, possibly by turning it into a `list`.

Comment: Excellent answer for so many technical justifications. FP is the way to go! Kudos to you sir.

Comment: map doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

`glob.glob("*_bac.hgx")` will get you the files. You can then use the `os.remove` function to delete the file in your loop.