# Calling list items in subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I was trying to call list time using subprocess.call . It seems that its not working. Any better way to do that.

```
import os, sys
import subprocess as sb


files_to_remove=['*.jpg','*.txt','*.gif']

for item in files_to_remove:
    try:
        **sb.call(['rm' %s]) %item** # not working 

    except:
        print 'no %s files in directory' %item
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the double star in your subprocess call?

Comment: If you did not have a blank except, the problem would be a lot more obvious, you also don't need a subprocess to do this

Comment: Suggest you take a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703668/deleting-certain-files-using-python).

Comment: the reason for double star is I was trying to bold it. Its not really used in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use a subprocess here

```
import glob
import os

files_to_remove = ['*.jpg', '*.txt', '*.gif']
for files_glob in files_to_remove:
    for filename in glob.glob(files_glob):
        os.remove(filename)
```

---

If we were to insist on using a subprocess (which we wouldn't for removing these files), we would do

```
import glob
import subprocess

files_to_remove=['*.jpg', '*.txt', '*.gif']

for files_glob in files_to_remove:
    matches = glob.glob(files_glob)
    if matches:
        subprocess.check_call(['rm'] + matches)
    else:
        print 'no %s files in directory' % files_glob
```

It's best never to use `shell=True`.

Comment: thanks. your first approach is great. Say if I have a directory (not files). How can I use glob in that scenario ? In subprocess I can do like this , rm -r <dir name>

Comment: You'd do `import shutil` and then `shutil.rmtree("/path/to/the/dir")`. Globbing isn't appropriate there--glob is the name if the `*` syntax in the shell, but in this scenario we don't have a path with a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work as expected, because it escapes the arguments. And the following works:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys
import subprocess as sb

files_to_remove=['*.jpg','*.txt','*.gif']

for item in files_to_remove:
    try:
        sb.check_call(['rm ' + item], shell=True)
    except sb.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.output)
    except:
        print("unknown error")
```